# OpenVPN client doesn't have "use default gateway on remote network" option

Tags: vpn, openvpn, windows-8.1

I am on Windows 8.1.

Trying to follow the advice from https://superuser.com/questions/178674/setting-vpn-to-go-through-certain-ips-and-not-others/178675#178675

VPN network I have is **TAP Adapter OAS NDIS 6.0** from **OpenVPN Technologies, Inc.**

This is what I see in **TCP/IP settings** section:

[image]

Please, advice, why I don't see "use default gateway on remote network" option here or how can I achieve the same result.

Comment: The option is most likely in the VPN client settings, not in network adapter settings.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen - where can I find this option?

Comment: I don't know the AS version of the client.  But in the FOSS version, you would use `--route-nopull`.

Comment: @Zoredache - where can I put this option?

Answer (score 1):

The option you are looking for is not in the network adapter settings. It is in the OpenVPN configuration, which is located at `C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\openvpn.ovpn`. The exact filename depends on your setup.

Comment: I found a file in **C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN Technologies\OpenVPN Client\etc\profile**. Please, look to it's content - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1aMSw2TMWNqMatVYa0PFtN6jsbgr-g_3nLaDyTHYVAJ4/pub - what is the option I can remove here to disable routing all traffic via VPN ?

Comment: Since this is automatically generated, you will have to find which program generates it and disable the option in that software. The option `route-nopull` is the one that needs to be here.